# How to install Windows 8 boot manager in a different partition?

Tags: boot, windows-8, mbr

The last time I installed Windows 7, the boot manager automatically got installed in a small hidden partition, and the main os into another partition. So, formatting the C: won't affect the boot manager.

Yesterday I wiped and repartitioned my HDD like this:

- 50 MB primary NTFS (meant for boot manager)
- 100 GB primary NTFS (for Windows 8)
- 50 GB primary NTFS (for Windows 7)
- Some logical partitions to install Ubuntu and other OS

I installed Windows 7 and then Windows 8, and now there is no OS choosing menu. System directly boots Windows 8 and the 50 MB partition is empty.

There is a way to boot Windows 7 and even Ubuntu directly from the Windows boot manager with EasyBCD. But How do I put the boot manager in the 50 MB partition?

Comment: Just a note to mention that the 100MB System Reserved Partition is created by the Windows 7 installer only if the drive is not pre-partitioned. If you install the OS in an existing partition, it will not create that extra partition for BitLocker and WinRE.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `CMD` (command prompt) as administrator.
2. Input `bcdboot d:\windows /s d:`

   It means, copy the boot files for the system `d:\windows` to drive D. If system is not
   installed in d:\ you need to change the path. We will get a message "boot files successfully created".
3. Open Disk Management by entering `diskmgmt.msc` in Start - Search, locate
   the D:\ partition and mark that active instead of C: — Note: Drive D should be a primary partition.

Now the computer should boot from Drive D. Now I can format my C: drive any number of times without messing up with the boot manager.